# Provide different bindings of same data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Using AngularJS, say an array `$scope.data.children` has item with the following structure:

```
{
 "sku" : "<sku>",
 "selected" : "<boolean>"
}
```

Would there be a simple way referencing all `selected = true` children, ideally represented in `$scope.data.components`?

So, for example, if

```
$scope.data.children = [
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : "true"},
    {"sku" : "B","selected" : "false"},
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : "true"},
    {"sku" : "D","selected" : "false"}
]
```

then

```
$scope.data.components = [
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : "true"},
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : "true"},
]
```

and if `$scope.data.children` is updated to `[{"sku" : "D","selected" : "true"}]`

then `$scope.data.components =`,

```
[
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : "true"},
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : "true"},
    {"sku" : "D","selected" : "true"}
]
```

Comment: `$scope.data.components = $filter('filter')($scope.data.children, {selected:'true'});`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. Unfortunately, I missed a detail, which is that children should be iteratively checked for truthiness. I've written a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352382/provide-different-views-automatically-to-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch("data.children", setSelected);

var setSelected = function () {
    var selected = []

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.children; i++) {
        if ($scope.data.children[i].selected == "true") {
            selected.push($scope.data.children[i];
        }
    }

    $scope.data.components = selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use underscore.js in your project. 
it makes your life 500% easier!

and your item.selected value is stored as string, not as boolean.

```
    $scope.data.children = _.filter($scope.data.components, function (item) {
        return item.selected == "true";
    });
```

http://underscorejs.org/#filter