# Provide different views automatically to data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Using AngularJS, say an array `$scope.data.children` has item with the following structure:

```
{
 "sku" : "<sku>",
 "selected" : <boolean>,
 "children" : []
}
```

Would there be a simple way referencing all `selected = true` children, ideally represented in `$scope.data.components`?

So, for example, if

```
[
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "A1","selected" : true, "children":[]},
      {"sku" : "A2","selected" : false, "children":[]}
    ]},
    {"sku" : "B","selected" : false, "children":[
      {"sku" : "B1","selected" : false, "children":[]},
      {"sku" : "B2","selected" : false, "children":[]}
    ]},
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "C1","selected" : true, "children":[]},
      {"sku" : "C2","selected" : false, "children":[]}
    ]},
    {"sku" : "D","selected" : false, "children":[
      {"sku" : "D1","selected" : false, "children":[]},
      {"sku" : "D2","selected" : false, "children":[]}
    ]}
]
```

then

```
$scope.data.components = [
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "A1","selected" : true, "children":[]},
    },
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "C1","selected" : true, "children":[]}
    }
]
```

if `$scope.data.children` is updated to `[{"sku" : "D","selected" : true}]`

then `$scope.data.components =`

```
[
    {"sku" : "A","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "A1","selected" : true, "children":[]},
    },
    {"sku" : "C","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "C1","selected" : true, "children":[]}
    },
    {"sku" : "D","selected" : true, "children":[
      {"sku" : "D2","selected" : true, "children":[]}
    }
]
```

To summarise the requirements:

1. Live view - changes against `$scope.data.children` or `$scope.data.components` should be reflected on both immediately.
2. Any depth of `children` elements should be checked for `selected == true`
3. Once a false is detected, no subchildren should be checked.
4. (optional but great if possible) Any reference to `component` will only display `children` with `selected == true`. So, if a reference to the `"sku":"A"` object is available at `node`, then `node.components` will return `node.children` where `"sku":"A"`'s children's `select == true`

Answer (score 0):

With your given sample json, i have tried one implementation using `forEach in angularjs`

I simply looped through `children array and constructed the component array when needed`

```
angular.forEach($scope.children, function(child) {
 var grandChildValue = 0; //value to check for component node already exist

  angular.forEach(child.children, function(grandChild) {
   if(grandChild.selected) {

      if(grandChildValue != 0) {
         // if node already exist means it will be added to children from here

        angular.forEach($scope.components, function(comp){
          if(comp.sku == child.sku) {
            comp.children.push(grandChild);
          }
        });
        return;
      }
    //if node doesn't exist, it will create the node in component array & children inserted
    grandChildValue++;
    $scope.components.push({
      "sku" : child.sku,
      "selected": child.selected,
      "children":[grandChild]
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Here is a working plunker with your code,

http://embed.plnkr.co/Yv6BaLQQY03TMsnv0yHk/preview

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We have an array of objects, each of these objects has an array of objects and so on. This looks like an array of trees, each node in that tree can have an arbitrary number of child nodes, and each of these child nodes can have an arbitrary number of children and so on. So the problem is about traversing a tree and selecting only the nodes which are "selected". If we encounter a node which is not selected, we do not check it's children.

So we will go over the array, and for each tree check if the root node is selected and if it is we do the same procedure on its children and return the tree.

```
var reduceTreeArray = function (trees) {
    return trees.reduce(function (acc, tree) { // walk over the array
        tree = getSelectedTree(tree);
        if (tree) { // check if we have at least one node
            acc.push(tree);
        }
        return acc; // acc stands for accumulator
    }, []);
};

var getSelectedTree = function (node) {
    if (node.selected) {
        return {
            sku: node.sku,
            selected: true,
            children: reduceTreeArray(node.children) // walk over its children
        };
    }
    return false; 
};

var selectedTrees = reduceTreeArray(trees);
```

These two mutually recursive functions gives as the desired result, the tree can be arbitrarily deep, although keep in mind that you can reach the call stack size.

Now about the live view. Since we can use angular, let's use the `$scope.$watch` method to get notified if the data structure has changed and recalculate the trees. So:

```
$scope.$watch('data.children', function (newChildren) {
    $scope.data.components = reduceTreeArray(newChildren);
}, true);
```

Notice that I passed the `true` value as second argument. This is because we have to do a deep watch, so we get notified even when the value inside an object changes, for example when someone changes `selected` value on an object.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEYYTEbNrk6EEbVFhgZQ?p=preview) with the above stuff.